# Is the word "Overtake" and the word "Meet" express the same meaning?

Tags: word-problem

A freight train leaves a station and travels at a rate of 30 miles per hour.   Two hours later, an express train leaves the same station travelling in the same direction at a rate of 50 miles per our.

In how many hours will the express train overtake the freight train?

OR

In how many hours will the express train meet the freight train?

Is the word "Overtake" and the  word "Meet" express the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more related to language than to mathematics, but one usually uses "overtake" about one vehicle catching up from behind and passing the other vehicle, while "meet" is used when they move in opposite directions and pass eachother.

Comment: They will overtake each other  in 10 minutes. But  does this mean they will also meet in 10 minutes?  I have to solve the second case ?

Comment: @rushdi As I said, I think it's bad English to ask about when the trains "meet", but I believe your two questions ask about exactly the same thing.

Comment: That's enough. Thank you.